# Modification of Trigger in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, triggers

If a trigger is already in function what will be the effect if i will replace a small part of it ,so many records are getting inserted in table A continuously in which the trigger is applied.

Trigger X is running in table A,
total records are getting insterted per minute are 1000
If i have replaced the trigger what will be the Impact of It for those service who are accesing the table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Oracle's Edition Based Redefinition (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_editions.htm#ADFNS020) may help you here.

Answer (score 1):

A CREATE TRIGGER DDL should have no impact on your running DML transactions. Exclusive locks are not required on the table in order to add the trigger.

A CREATE OR REPLACE DDL is slightly different. It has to change an existing object. If the trigger is actively firing, the new trigger will try to lock the trigger object in the library cache before altering it. No impact on the table.

I generally observe that triggers execute immediately.

If you have tested your trigger, you should have no issues. If the trigger is correct, it will go into effect, and the impact shall be according to the logic that you've written in the trigger. The act of creating the trigger is not of concern, but the correctness of the trigger code is. So test it well.

Any transactions underway at the time you create the trigger will finish without firing the trigger.

Any future transactions will fire the trigger.